# Partial View in a column with Kendo UI grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to display a partial view in a Kendo UI grid cell.

For example, I imagine it like this (I know it doesn't work):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(x => x.Id);
        columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
        columns.Bound(x => x.Field1);
        columns.Template(@<text></text>)
            .ClientTemplate(
                "<div>'" + Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", x.SubViewModel) + "</div>");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
    )
)
```

I found that I could do it with jQuery which would render the call to an Action Method. But is there a simplest way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to render in the cell? I can't imagine rendering a partial view in a cell is the best way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to render some sub properties from my original view model. It looks like a list of days that can be colored or not.

Comment: I've been trying to do something very similar and failed.  To my knowledge Kendo grid only likes flat data.  The only way I can think of is to create a sub grid.  I know this was posted a while ago, hope you found a solution

Comment: Any joy with this? Thinking I'd like to do the same.

Comment: Sadly not for now with the actual Kendo UI version.

Answer (score 1):

I use a ClientRowTemplate to achieve something similar to the above.

Look at this documentation: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/rowtemplate

Basically I define my Row template in a partial view then I render the partial like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("usersManageGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.LoginId).Visible(false);
              columns.Bound(c => c.FullName).Title("Name").Width(120);      
              columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Title("Username");
          }).ClientRowTemplate(Html.Partial("_TestPartial").ToHtmlString()))
```

You can still specify and bind to other columns like the documentation shows. You can also pass in your sub view model if you wish as normal;

```
.ClientRowTemplate(Html.Partial("_TestPartial",x.SubViewModel).ToHtmlString())
```

The partial view which contains the row template looks like this:

```
<tr data-uid='#: LoginId #'>
    <td>
       <span class='description'><b>Name</b> : #: FullName# </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.Partial("_Test2Partial")
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then you will see I render another partial view for the second column which simply has this in it:

```
<span style="color:purple;"><b>Email</b> : #: Email# </span>
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]